# can we compare two RDF statements?

Tags: rdf, rdfs

I have a question regarding rdf statements.
Can we compare two rdf statements?
For Example, I receive a statement from the store, can I compare that with a pre-defined statement for the values of say object?
Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you trying to compare statements for equality?  I get the feeling you might be going off in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

two RDF statements are equals if their components (subject, predicate , object) are equals.

from: http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-concepts/

> Two RDF URI references are equal if and only if they compare as equal,
>   character by character, as Unicode strings.
>
> Two literals are equal if and only if all of the following hold:
>
> ```
> The strings of the two lexical forms compare equal, character by character.
> Either both or neither have language tags.
> The language tags, if any, compare equal.
> Either both or neither have datatype URIs.
> The two datatype URIs, if any, compare equal, character by character.
> ```

Comment: You leave out the hard part, bnodes.  Which are comparable in terms of graph isomorphism.  With a single statement, it's murky.  Same id could denote the same resource, but it could also mean different resources with the same id (by accident) from different, not equal, RDF graphs.